# Displaying points with customized time using Waveform Chart in Labview

Tags: charts, labview, waveform

I'd like to display some points on a Waveform Graph in LabView. However, the points won't be acquired at a constant rate. Therefore I'd like to be able to add the current time to the plot together with the displayed value. Is there a way to do it?

I know I can use the XY Graph, but I like the functionality of the Waveform Chart - I can display only last few seconds and the usage is much simpler (there is no need to unbundle the data, concentrate the arrays and bundle them again).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this if you wire a `waveform` to the chart and provide a new `t0` each time you receive a new sample.

#### Example

[image: Multirate Data Waveform Chart]

*NB: I used next-value interpolation to more clearly show that each line segment has a different interval.*

#### Block Diagram

[image: LabVIEW 2013 Snippet]

Comment: Great answer, thanks Joe! I've been using LabVIEW for aaages and had never figured this one out!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no built in XY Chart. There are several threads on the topic and this Knowledge Base article: [How Do I Make an XY Graph Behave as an XY Chart?](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/18B56D8556D44BF18625753D006EFF7C)